# How to redirect stderr of ${var:?"foo"} syntax?

Tags: bash, stderr

I am using bash and I am trying to print a message to standard error if a variable is not set with the following command:

```
echo ${var:?"This var is not set"}
```

Now, I want to redirect that error message to a file. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
echo ${var:?"This var is not set"} > testfile
```

Nor the following worked:

```
echo ${var:?"This var is not set"} 2> testfile
```

So, how can I direct this generated message to a file?

Answer (score 0):

From [*Bash Reference Manual*](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ```
> ${parameter:?word}
> ```
>
> If `parameter` is null or unset, the expansion of `word` (or a message to that effect if `word` is not present) is written to the standard error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits. Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

It may not be obvious but "standard error" here means the standard error *of the shell*. When you do `echo … 2> testfile` you redirect standard error of `echo`. They both normally end up in your terminal but are not the same.

To make it work as you want create a subshell and redirect *its* standard error:

```
(echo ${var:?"This var is not set"}) 2> testfile
```

This will also work:

```
{ echo ${var:?"This var is not set"}; } 2> testfile
```

Note the actual command (`echo`) will inherit the already redirected standard error of the subshell, so effectively this redirection affects them both. It hardly ever matters when the command is `echo` but with a command that returns error message it does. Compare:

```
unset var
(dd ${var:?"This var is not set"}) 2> testfile
cat testfile
var=foo
(dd ${var:?"This var is not set"}) 2> testfile
cat testfile
```